# how to get next random double on an open interval (x, y)

Tags: java, random, intervals

I know the basic algorithm for a random number in a half-closed interval is:

```
Random rand = new Random();
double increment = min + (max - min) * rand.nextDouble();
```

This will give you a random number on the interval `[min, max)` because [`nextDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextDouble()) includes 0 in the range of results (`[0.0,1.0)`) that it returns.  Is there a good way to exclude the minimum value and instead provide a random number on `(min, max)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In *theory*, calling [`Math.nextUp(double d)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#nextUp-double-) should do it.

```
double minUp = Math.nextUp(min);
double increment = minUp + (max - minUp) * rand.nextDouble();
```

In reality, rounding after multiplication may still cause `min` to be returned, so a retry loop would be better. Given the rarity of an exact `min` value, performance won't suffer.

```
double increment;
do {
    increment = min + (max - min) * rand.nextDouble();
} while (increment <= min || increment >= max);
```

Just for heck of it, I also added a `max` check.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than asking for the minimum exclusively, you could ask for it inclusively -- but have the minimum be the next value of double using [`Math::nextUp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#nextUp-double-):

```
min = Math.nextUp(min);
```

Doubles are discrete, so this is analogous to in integer-land, rephrasing `(0, 10)` as `[1, 10)`.

Comment: I think [`nextUp()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#nextUp-double-) is better than [`+= ulp()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ulp-double-).